# Ionic: Connection to server was unsuccessful

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, connection

When I try to run ionic app in emulator or device. I get the following error:

> The connection to server was unsuccessful (http://192.168.0.8:8100)

However, it works alright in browser through `ionic serve`.

I hope it is not due to `Content Security Tag` or `Cordova Whitelist plugin` settings which are as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible issues:

1. Check if device is under the same Wi-Fi.
2. Check if you firewall is not blocking 8100 and 35729 ports.
3. Check the following tags:

   `<content src="index.html"/>
   <access origin="*"/>
   <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*"/>
   <allow-navigation href="*"/>
   <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.8:8100"/>
   <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
   <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>`

Comment: Why 192.168.0.8 ?